# Windows 10 Folder doesn't show pictures/video properties at bottom

Tags: user-folders

I'm trying to see picture properties at the bottom of folders with video and jpgs. In Win 7, when you highlight a picture or video, you see the properties at the bottom of the folder. When I upgraded to 10, this disappeared. Any idea how to enable this in 10? File size, video length, when taken video pixel width and height?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the feature has moved to the Details pane (which is now on the right of the window), You can find it by opening the `View` settings, then selecting the `Details pane` button.

[image: Details Pane]